# Pandas dataframe combine duplicate columns into one- separate data by comma

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My dataframe has few duplicate column names. If a duplicate column name is found combine duplicate columns into one. I also want to retain duplicate columns data separated by comma. Can anyone please suggest a way to do this.

I have constructed an example below. In my actual dataframe column names are unknown.

Input DataFrame:

```
  Col1 Col2 Col3 Col2
A  CA1  CA5  CA3  CA5
B  CB1  CB5  CB3  CB5
C  CC1  CC5  CC3  CC5
D  CD1  CD5  CD3  None
E  CE1  CE5  CE3  CE5
```

It can be read with:

```
df = pd.read_clipboard(names=['Col1','Col2','Col3','Col2'], skiprows=1)
```

Output DataFrame:

```
  Col1     Col2 Col3
A  CA1  CA5,CA5  CA3
B  CB1  CB5,CB5  CB3
C  CC1  CC5,CC5  CC3
D  CD1  CD5  CD3
E  CE1  CE5,CE5  CE3
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could also:

```
df.groupby(df.columns, axis=1).agg(lambda x: ','.join(x.values)))

      Col1     Col2 Col3
Index                   
A      CA1  CA2,CA5  CA3
B      CB1  CB2,CB5  CB3
C      CC1  CC2,CC5  CC3
D      CD1  CD2,CD5  CD3
E      CE1  CE2,CE5  CE3
```

In detail: Use `.groupby()` on the `df.columns` to group duplicates:

```
df.groupby(df.columns, axis=1).apply(lambda x: x.info())

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Index: 5 entries, A to E
Data columns (total 1 columns):
Col1    5 non-null object
dtypes: object(1)
memory usage: 80.0+ bytes
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Index: 5 entries, A to E
Data columns (total 2 columns):
Col2    5 non-null object
Col2    5 non-null object
dtypes: object(2)
memory usage: 120.0+ bytes
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Index: 5 entries, A to E
Data columns (total 1 columns):
Col3    5 non-null object
dtypes: object(1)
```

then, use `.agg()` with `','.join()` to collapse the `.values` in the `grouped` columns, which look as follows:

```
df.groupby(df.columns, axis=1).apply(lambda x: x.values)

Col1                  [[CA1], [CB1], [CC1], [CD1], [CE1]]
Col2    [[CA5, CA5], [CB5, CB5], [CC5, CC5], [CD5, CD5...
Col3                  [[CA3], [CB3], [CC3], [CD3], [CE3]]
```

Since only duplicate columns have more than a single value, only they will be joined, so that you get:

```
      Col1     Col2 Col3
Index                   
A      CA1  CA5,CA5  CA3
B      CB1  CB5,CB5  CB3
C      CC1  CC5,CC5  CC3
D      CD1  CD5,CD5  CD3
E      CE1  CE5,CE5  CE3
```

With `None` type values, you could:

```
df.groupby(df.columns, axis=1).apply(lambda x: x.apply(lambda y: ','.join([l for l in y if l is not None]), axis=1))
```

to get:

```
      Col1     Col2 Col3
Index                   
A      CA1  CA5,CA5  CA3
B      CB1  CB5,CB5  CB3
C      CC1  CC5,CC5  CC3
D      CD1      CD5  CD3
E      CE1  CE5,CE5  CE3
```

Comment: That's right, there was a `.values` missing, sorry.

Comment: Thanks Stefan, Yes I was missing .values. My actual dataframe has some None values for that it is throwing errors. Do you know how to sort this?

I have updated this in my question above.

Comment: See updated, slightly more convoluted because I think you have to check all rows.

Comment: Fantastic code. Worked very well. Thanks very much.

Comment: Excellent idea! I only encounter a problem with NaNs. I still get them in the combined field, like "MyString,nan". I tried to solve this by using `l for l in y if l != np.nan` but I still get them. Any ideas?

Comment: Since I've got also floats in my dataframe and thus it won't work plus there are NaNs I've found this solution working for me:
`df.groupby(df.columns, axis=1).agg(lambda x: x.apply(lambda y: ','.join([str(l) for l in y if str(l) != "nan"]), axis=1))`

Answer (score 6):

you can do it this way:

```
df.T.groupby(level=0).agg(','.join).T
```

Data:

```
In [207]: df
Out[207]:
      Col1 Col2 Col1 Col2 Col3
Index
A      CA1  CA2  CA3  CA5  ZA1
B      CB1  CB2  CB3  CB5  ZA2
C      CC1  CC2  CC3  CC5  ZA3
D      CD1  CD2  CD3  CD5  ZA4
E      CE1  CE2  CE3  CE5  ZA5
```

Output:

```
In [208]: df.T.groupby(level=0).agg(','.join).T
Out[208]:
          Col1     Col2 Col3
Index
A      CA1,CA3  CA2,CA5  ZA1
B      CB1,CB3  CB2,CB5  ZA2
C      CC1,CC3  CC2,CC5  ZA3
D      CD1,CD3  CD2,CD5  ZA4
E      CE1,CE3  CE2,CE5  ZA5
```

Explanation:

```
In [209]: df.T
Out[209]:
Index    A    B    C    D    E
Col1   CA1  CB1  CC1  CD1  CE1
Col2   CA2  CB2  CC2  CD2  CE2
Col1   CA3  CB3  CC3  CD3  CE3
Col2   CA5  CB5  CC5  CD5  CE5
Col3   ZA1  ZA2  ZA3  ZA4  ZA5

In [210]: df.T.groupby(level=0).agg(','.join)
Out[210]:
Index        A        B        C        D        E
Col1   CA1,CA3  CB1,CB3  CC1,CC3  CD1,CD3  CE1,CE3
Col2   CA2,CA5  CB2,CB5  CC2,CC5  CD2,CD5  CE2,CE5
Col3       ZA1      ZA2      ZA3      ZA4      ZA5
```

Comment: This is the most "pandas-thonic" solution.

Answer (score 2):

It works in string and non-string columns also

```
def cobinecols(y):
        return ','.join(y[y.notnull()].astype(str))
df = df.groupby(level=0, axis=1).apply(lambda y: y.apply(cobinecols, axis=1))
```

**Output:**

```
   Col1  Col2    Col3
A  CA1  CA5,CA5  CA3
B  CB1  CB5,CB5  CB3
C  CC1  CC5,CC5  CC3
D  CD1  CD5      CD3  
E  CE1  CE5,CE5  CE3
```

Answer (score 1):

I feel ashamed to post this.  But it works.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice(('a', 'b', 'c'), (5, 4)), list('ABCDE'), ['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3', 'Col2'])

pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(c) for i, c in df.iteritems()], axis=1, keys=range(len(df.columns))).swaplevel(0, 1, 1).sort_index(1).groupby(level=0, axis=1).apply(lambda df: df.apply(lambda x: ','.join(x.values), axis=1))
```

Broken down a bit.

```
df2 = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(c) for i, c in df.iteritems()],
                axis=1, keys=range(len(df.columns)))

a1 = lambda df: df.apply(lambda x: ','.join(x.values), axis=1)
gb = df2.swaplevel(0, 1, 1).sort_index(1).groupby(level=0, axis=1)
gb.apply(a1)

  Col1 Col2 Col3
A    a  c,b    a
B    a  c,c    c
C    a  a,b    b
D    b  c,c    a
E    a  c,b    a
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function to merge columns quickly with some different methods depending on the task. Is faster than the groupby if not 100% of columns are duplicated...

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def merge_duplicated_columns(df, method="join", sep=","):
    duplicated =  df.columns[df.columns.duplicated()].unique()
    
    if method == "join":
        for d in duplicated:
            df[d] = df.pop(d).fillna("").astype(str).apply(
                sep.join, axis=1).str.replace(
                    r"(?<=\|)\|", "", regex=True).str.strip(sep).replace("", np.nan)   
            
    elif method == "unique":
        for d in duplicated:
            df[d] = df.pop(d).fillna("").astype(str).apply(
                lamba x: sep.join(x.unique()),                
                axis=1).str.replace(
                    r"(?<=\|)\|", "", regex=True).str.strip(sep).replace("", np.nan)             
                    
    elif method == "sum":
        for d in duplicated:
            df[d] = df.pop(d).sum(axis=1)
        
    return df
```