# How to convert duplicate column names python dataframe to json

Tags: python, json, dataframe, dictionary

How to convert dataframe to json

df:

```
     Name     City   Email          City 
     Andrew   Tokyo  abc@mail.com   Sydney
```

Required format

```
json_required = {'Name': 'Andrew',
'City': 'Tokyo',
'Email': 'abc@mail.com',
'City': 'Sydney'}
```

Comment: A json is not expected to have duplicate keys at same level. Its not a valid JSON then.

Comment: So is there any way where i can concatenate duplicate column name values and then i will be left with unique column names and then it can be converted to json easily .

Comment: dataframe itself has 2 cols with same name? how are you getting the data into the df? from files?

Comment: You can use a JSON array like `"City": ["Tokyo", "Sydney"]`.  Use this [approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37932756/995052) to merge your duplicate columns and then make it a json

Comment: You can check out [pandas.DataFrame.to_json](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since dictionaries can't have duplicate keys, one way is to create a list of items for those who were about to be in duplicate keys. The below solution will create a list of dictionaries. This could be useful if you have a dataframe with more than 1 row.

```
out = df.groupby(df.columns, axis=1).agg(lambda x: x.to_numpy().tolist() if x.shape[1]>1 else x.to_numpy().flatten()).to_dict('records')
```

Output:

```
[{'City': ['Tokyo', 'Sydney'], 'Email': 'abc@mail.com', 'Name': 'Andrew'}]
```